# Validating Timestamp format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ in java?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I'm trying to do a **timestamp** validation using **joda time-1.6.2**. Please point my error and help me out.
**Code**

```
String timestamp = "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z";
String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

try {
             DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
             dateFormatter.parseDateTime(timestamp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Timestamp is invalid format" + e);
        }
```

**Exception**

```
INFO: Timestamp is invalid formatjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z" is malformed at "Z"
```

Comment: What should `Z`be in timestamp? Is it a constant?

Comment: Can't I use this format or pattern with Z

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda why T is like 'T'? but in your timeStamp is T?

Comment: @KickButtowski that's how you specify a literal character `T` in the pattern, instead of indicating a type of field to the formatter.

Comment: No need for a formatter. You can pass an ISO 8601 compliant string directly to the constructor of a DateTime, or to `DateTime.parse`.

Comment: There is a T in the middle and a Z at the end??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In order to not just get a vaild timestamp format, but also have zero offset from **UTC** use

```
String timestamp = "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z";
DateTime dt = new DateTime(timestamp, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

#### Otherwise / Pitfalls

When not explicitly specifying the timestamp as UTC, zero offset from local time might be assumed. Also while following might be a valid pattern, it is somewhat misleading.

```
String timestamp = "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z";
String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
```

As described by Meno, this treats the zero time zone offset as a literal (therefore ignoring it).

Also considers pumping up Meno Hochschild's answer for explaining this in better detail, since I am not allowed to delete mine for now (accepted answer).

Comment: **Incorrect** answer. See the [answer by Meno Hochschild](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26014153/642706) for details.

Answer (score 10):

I am very sceptical about treating Z just as literal. **The char Z has a meaning, namely zero offset.** The documentation of [Joda-Time version 1.6](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-1.6/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis()) says about this code:

```
String timestamp = "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z";
DateTime dt = 
  ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(timestamp).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dt); // 2014-09-23T23:03:11.000Z
```

> Returns a formatter that combines a full date and time without millis,
>   separated by a 'T' (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ). The time zone offset is
>   'Z' for zero, and of the form '±HH:mm' for non-zero.

**Now let's view at following four alternatives in detail (explicitly tested with version 1.6.2):**

```
String timestamp = "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z";
DateTimeZone utc = DateTimeZone.UTC;

DateTime dt1 = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(timestamp).withZone(utc);
System.out.println(dt1); // 2014-09-23T23:03:11.000Z (OK)

DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(timestamp, utc);
System.out.println(dt2); // 2014-09-23T23:03:11.000Z (OK)

DateTime dt3 =
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parseDateTime(timestamp).withZone(utc);
System.out.println(dt3); //2014-09-23T21:03:11.000Z (WRONG!!!)

DateTime dt4 =
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ").parseDateTime(timestamp).withZone(utc);
// exception: Invalid format: "2014-09-23T23:03:11Z" is malformed at "Z"
```

**Conclusion:** The other answers given so far treating Z as literal are wrong because the input is treated in local timezone, not with offset UTC+00:00. Use either the constructor or the specific class `IsoDateTimeFormat` (I would prefer latter one for clarity).

**About the exception:** This is a bug solved with version 2.0, see [release-notes](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/upgradeto200.html). You should better update your library version.

> Allow 'Z' and 'ZZ' in format patterns to parse 'Z' as '+00:00'
>   [2827359]

Comment: +1 for calling out that treating 'Z' as a literal is bad because it does not interpret it as a time zone that way.  I assumed the reader would recognize that but have updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Thx for pointing this out, updated my answer as well! Yours seems to be the most complete answer/explanation.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild just question, is it a malformed format? 2015-11-17T00:00:00+0000Z , is possible to have +0000 and Z at same time?

Comment: @Zilevav That is double information (redundant) and would require two pattern symbols for parsing (must be different - something like "zXXX" in `SimpleDateFormat`, "X" is not supported by Joda-Time). Not a good idea. Worse, what will you do if the offset in input is ambivalent (for example "...+01:00Z")? `SimpleDateFormat` just uses the first offset "+01" and ignores the second (Z = "00:00"), even in strict mode, tested by me.

Answer (score 7):

From the [v1.6 API documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-1.6/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

When you specify `Z` (without single quotes) in your pattern, the value in your timestamp must be in the format `+HHMM` or `-HHMM` as a numeric offset from UTC.  The literal character `Z` is not valid input for the specified format.

Examples:

- 2014-09-23T23:03:11+0000
- 2014-09-23T23:03:11-0500
- 2014-09-23T23:03:11+0430

As [Levit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680919/levit) mentioned in the other answer, if the goal is to accept a literal 'Z' in the input timestamp *without treating it as a time zone* (bad idea) then the *Z* character can be quoted using single quotes in the pattern (`...'Z'`). That is similar to what was done for the literal 'T' that separates the date components from the time components.  Treating `Z` in the input as a literal is not recommended because it has meaning and, if provided, the time zone is an important component of the timestamp.

Comment: +1 This also provides a good explanation/description regarding the meaning of the `Z` character!