# How do I properly add a 'Z' at the end of a datetime that's marshalled by Spring MVC with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jodatime

I have a DateTimeXmlAdapter that I'm using to convert Joda dates to Strings. It looks as follows:

```
public class DateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
    private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(PATTERN);

    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String value) {
        return formatter.parseDateTime(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(DateTime value) {
        return formatter.print(value);
    }
}
```

This results in the following string in XML:

```
2014-10-16T18:31:57-0400
```

However, the endpoint I'm sending this to expects a 'Z' at the end instead of -0400. They recommend converting to UTC so timezone information doesn't need to be sent. Makes sense to me. However, I can't seem to get a 'Z' to be at the end unless I state it literally. As in:

```
private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
```

The discussion below seems to indicate that adding the Z is not recommended.

[Validating Timestamp format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009841/validating-timestamp-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-in-java/26014153#26014153)

It tried changing it to the following, but this results in a date w/o the 'Z'.

```
public class DateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond().withZoneUTC();

    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String value) {
        return formatter.parseDateTime(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(DateTime value) {
        return formatter.print(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-10-17T18:50:43
```

The endpoint I'm talking to says they need the 'Z' because it indicates zero offset from UTC. What's the proper way to add a 'Z' at the end when using Joda Time and JAXB?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of method [ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinuteSecond()) is not appropriate because it does not output the offset (in your case this is Z = UTC+00:00). Instead you can use the method [dateTimeNoMillis()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis()), and of course you need to change the `DateTime`-object to UTC-offset:

```
public class DateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withZoneUTC();

    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String value) {
        return formatter.parseDateTime(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(DateTime value) {
        return formatter.print(value);
    }
}
```

**From the documentation:**

> Returns a formatter that combines a full date and time without millis,
>   separated by a 'T' (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ).  The time zone offset is
>   'Z' for zero, and of the form '±HH:mm' for non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

With `Z` vs. without `Z` is a known timezone vs. unknown timezone. See this question:

[Semantics of the xsd:dateTime without timezone and its conversion to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518217/semantics-of-the-xsddatetime-without-timezone-and-its-conversion-to-date)

I'd suggest converting Joda `DateTime` not to `String` but to `XMLGregorianCalendar` which is much more elaborate on the timezone etc. fields. JAXB will then take care of `XMLGregorianCalendar` marshalling (or unmarshalling).

See:

- `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance()`
- `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond, timezone)` - set the last one to `0` for `Z`